# how to localize content type, site columns in sharepoint 2013 online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to localize content type, site columns, list with no luck . I have created the site columns , content types using CSOM. Here is my code of creating content type. i have tried to call as `$Resources.SiteCol_ContentType_Title` but its not working

```
public void CreateContentType(ClientContext ctx, string ctTitle, string ctDescription, string ctId)
    {
        try

        {
            if (!ctx.Web.ContentTypeExistsById(ctId))
            {
                ctx.Web.CreateContentType(ctTitle, ctDescription, ctId, ContentTypes.DefaultCTGroup);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logErrors(ctx, "cannot create content type", ex.Message);

        }
    }
```

created one .cs file for getting the name,displayname and id of content type .

```
public class ContentTypes
{      
    public const string TestCtTitle = "TestCT";
    public const string TestCtId = "0x0100A07C46CB2F9A46C4A32B831A1716EAB8";
    public const string TestCtDesc = "test content type";      
}
```

any one has done?